# On the uniqueness of SVD in the $2$-dimensional case

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, rotations, svd

On page 155 of Tristan Needham's [Visual Differential Geometry and Forms](https://press.princeton.edu/books/hardcover/9780691203690/visual-differential-geometry-and-forms), the singular value decomposition (SVD) is given by

$$M = R_{\phi} \circ \Sigma \circ R_{-\theta}$$

with the associated picture:

---

[image: page 155 of Needham's book]

---

I am a bit confused as to why we actually rotate by $-\theta$ , expand then rotate back? Couldn't we just expand then rotate so the circle to the ellipse?

Comment: SVD shows that some pair of **mutually orthogonal** axes is mapped to some other pair of **mutually orthogonal** axes. In the picture, the axes in question are the solid axis and the dotted axis in the top-left figure. They are mapped to the solid and dotted axes in the top-right figure. If you expand the circle in the top-left figure in horizontal and vertical directions (by factors $\sigma_1$ and $\sigma_2$) and then rotate it, the angle between the two axes will no longer be a right angle (unless $\sigma_1=\sigma_2$).

Comment: I am very confused why won't the two axes have a right angle? @user1551 could you explain in more details?